# How to find middle value of a list and return the higher value if there are an even number of items

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am taking a dictionary as input and outputing the middle/upper value. For example, `mydict = {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 9, 'd': 11}`, the output is 9.

```
def middlest_value(mydict):
    sorteddict = sorted(mydict.values())
    return len(sorteddict)//2
```

This is my function. I convert the dictionary values into a list, and then sort them by the `sorted`. When I try to find the middle/upper value... the lower value returns when its odd.

I thought about adding + 1 within the return statement to increase the index by 1, but it failed.

Comment: Your function returns half the length of your dictionary--so the _index_ of the middle value. Is this what you are expecting? Or are you expecting the actual _value_?

Comment: I'm expecting middle value of the middle index when even. But if the values have a length of an odd index, I expect it to output the index value + 1. For example, list [1,3, 9,11] has 4 values. I expect the output to be 9 not 3 nor (3+9)/2.

Answer (score 0):

[`statistics.median_high`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median_high) does what you want:

```
import statistics

mydict = {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 9, 'd': 11}
statistics.median_high(mydict.values())
```

FYI, your code is returning what could be used as an index for a middle value, not the value itself.